# Magento 2 | Override Magento_Downloadable

Tags: magento2, module, overrides, downloadable

I want to override this file in my module:

> /var/www/magento2-dev/vendor/magento/module-downloadable/Helper/Download.php

to

> /var/www/magento2-dev/app/code/My/Module/Helper/Download.php

How can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please add preference in di.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Downloadable\Helper\Download" type="My\Module\Helper\Download"/>
</config>
```

and make your helper

```
 namespace My\Module\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException as CoreException;


class Download extends Magento\Downloadable\Helper
{
/**
 * Link type url
 */
const LINK_TYPE_URL = 'url';

/**
 * Link type file
 */
const LINK_TYPE_FILE = 'file';

/**
 * Config path to content disposition
 */
const XML_PATH_CONTENT_DISPOSITION = 'catalog/downloadable/content_disposition';

/**
 * Type of link
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $_linkType = self::LINK_TYPE_FILE;

/**
 * Resource file
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $_resourceFile = null;

/**
 * Resource open handle
 *
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\File\ReadInterface
 */
protected $_handle = null;

/**
 * Remote server headers
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $_urlHeaders = [];

/**
 * MIME Content-type for a file
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $_contentType = 'application/octet-stream';

/**
 * File name
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $_fileName = 'download';

/**
 * Core file storage database
 *
 * @var \Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Storage\Database
 */
protected $_coreFileStorageDb;

/**
 * Downloadable file
 *
 * @var \Magento\Downloadable\Helper\File
 */
protected $_downloadableFile;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem
 */
protected $_filesystem;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\File\ReadFactory
 */
protected $fileReadFactory;

/**
 * Working Directory (valid for LINK_TYPE_FILE only).
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\Read
 */
protected $_workingDirectory;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface
 */
protected $_session;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context
 * @param File $downloadableFile
 * @param \Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Storage\Database $coreFileStorageDb
 * @param Filesystem $filesystem
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface $session
 * @param Filesystem\File\ReadFactory $fileReadFactory
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
    \Magento\Downloadable\Helper\File $downloadableFile,
    \Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Storage\Database $coreFileStorageDb,
    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
    \Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface $session,
    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\File\ReadFactory $fileReadFactory
) {
    parent::__construct($context,$downloadableFile,$coreFileStorageDb,$filesystem,$session,$fileReadFactory);
    $this->_downloadableFile = $downloadableFile;
    $this->_coreFileStorageDb = $coreFileStorageDb;
    $this->_filesystem = $filesystem;
    $this->_session = $session;
    $this->fileReadFactory = $fileReadFactory;
}

/**
 * Retrieve Resource file handle (socket, file pointer etc)
 *
 * @return \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\File\ReadInterface
 * @throws CoreException|\Exception
 */
protected function _getHandle()
{
    if (!$this->_resourceFile) {
        throw new CoreException(__('Please set resource file and link type.'));
    }

    if (is_null($this->_handle)) {
        if ($this->_linkType == self::LINK_TYPE_URL) {
            $path = $this->_resourceFile;
            $protocol = strtolower(parse_url($path, PHP_URL_SCHEME));
            if ($protocol) {
                // Strip down protocol from path
                $path = preg_replace('#.+://#', '', $path);
            }
            $this->_handle = $this->fileReadFactory->create($path, $protocol);
        } elseif ($this->_linkType == self::LINK_TYPE_FILE) {
            $this->_workingDirectory = $this->_filesystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
            $fileExists = $this->_downloadableFile->ensureFileInFilesystem($this->_resourceFile);
            if ($fileExists) {
                $this->_handle = $this->_workingDirectory->openFile($this->_resourceFile);
            } else {
                throw new CoreException(__('Invalid download link type.'));
            }
        } else {
            throw new CoreException(__('Invalid download link type.'));
        }
    }
    return $this->_handle;
}

/**
 * Retrieve file size in bytes
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getFileSize()
{
    return $this->_getHandle()->stat($this->_resourceFile)['size'];
}

/**
 * Return MIME type of a file.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getContentType()
{
    $this->_getHandle();
    if ($this->_linkType == self::LINK_TYPE_FILE) {
        if (function_exists(
            'mime_content_type'
        ) && ($contentType = mime_content_type(
            $this->_workingDirectory->getAbsolutePath($this->_resourceFile)
        ))
        ) {
            return $contentType;
        } else {
            return $this->_downloadableFile->getFileType($this->_resourceFile);
        }
    } elseif ($this->_linkType == self::LINK_TYPE_URL) {
        return $this->_handle->stat($this->_resourceFile)['type'];
    }
    return $this->_contentType;
}

/**
 * Return name of the file
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getFilename()
{
    $this->_getHandle();
    if ($this->_linkType == self::LINK_TYPE_FILE) {
        return pathinfo($this->_resourceFile, PATHINFO_BASENAME);
    } elseif ($this->_linkType == self::LINK_TYPE_URL) {
        $stat = $this->_handle->stat($this->_resourceFile);
        if (isset($stat['disposition'])) {
            $contentDisposition = explode('; ', $stat['disposition']);
            if (!empty($contentDisposition[1]) && preg_match(
                '/filename=([^ ]+)/',
                $contentDisposition[1],
                $matches
            )
            ) {
                return $matches[1];
            }
        }
        $fileName = @pathinfo($this->_resourceFile, PATHINFO_BASENAME);
        if ($fileName) {
            return $fileName;
        }
    }
    return $this->_fileName;
}

/**
 * Set resource file for download
 *
 * @param string $resourceFile
 * @param string $linkType
 * @return $this
 * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
 */
public function setResource($resourceFile, $linkType = self::LINK_TYPE_FILE)
{
    if (self::LINK_TYPE_FILE == $linkType) {
        //check LFI protection
        if (preg_match('#\.\.[\\\/]#', $resourceFile)) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException(
                'Requested file may not include parent directory traversal ("../", "..\\" notation)'
            );
        }
    }

    $this->_resourceFile = $resourceFile;
    $this->_linkType = $linkType;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Output file contents
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function output()
{
    $handle = $this->_getHandle();
    $this->_session->writeClose();
    while (true == ($buffer = $handle->read(1024))) {
        echo $buffer;
    }
}

/**
 * Use Content-Disposition: attachment
 *
 * @param mixed $store
 * @return bool
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.BooleanGetMethodName)
 */
public function getContentDisposition($store = null)
{
    return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_CONTENT_DISPOSITION, \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE, $store);
}
```

}